# Amazon S3 permissions don't specify public access however public can read objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-control-list

I've got an AWS S3 bucket where the only permissions I've defined are for myself and Amazon's Log Delivery.  As shown from the AWS Console:

[image: aws s3 bucket perms 1]

As shown from another tool (S3 Browser):

[image: aws s3 bucket perms 2]

There's no public or everyone or anonymous users in the ACL.

Yet, public/anonymous users can read objects from the bucket:

[image: public access]

How can this be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

S3 has [three ways to control access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html):

- IAM
- Bucket Policy
- ACLs

I suspect you have a bucket policy that provides public access.

A bucket policy like this, which you haven't mentioned, would provide public access.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "AddPerm",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action": "s3:GetObject",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yup.  I incorrectly assumed that the console and other tools would show me the full set of permissions regardless of where they came from...

Comment: Nope. S3 is the most confusing of the main AWS products with regards to security. I suspect it's partly due to legacy backwards compatibility.